# UITableViewCell : UITapGestureRecognizer unrecognized selector sent to instance error

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a `UITapGestureRecognizer` on a `UILabel` in a `UITableViewCell`, I add the target of the said `UITapGestureRecognizer` as the view controller, as in:

```
class Cell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        let tap1 = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: ViewController(), action:  "selectLabel:")
        label.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
    }
 }

class ViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate{

    fun selectLabel(gesture: UITapGestureRecognizer){
         //animate some view in custom cell
    }
 }
```

However, I am getting a "UITapGestureRecognizer unrecognized selector sent to instance" error.

Comment: Can you tell us what "ViewController()" stands for? :)

Answer (score 0):

Set gesture on `cellForRowAtIndexPath.`

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CellIdentifier", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! Cell
    let tap1 = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:  "selectLabel:")
    cell.label.addGestureRecognizer(tap1)
    return cell
  }
```

Comment: Doing this will create a strong reference cycle, unless you remove the gesture in, for example, `prepareForReuse` with: `gestureRecognizers?.forEach(removeGestureRecognizer)`.